# VBA Excel to fix a bug in a heading

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bug in my heading section and I cant solve it completely. I am currently writing macros for an Excel file. We import items (like heading, id, name, description etc) from a tool we use which is called Jama.

Previously, Excel was generating a bug like when the heading was 2.13 it was generating 2,13. We solved it using `.NumberFormat="@"` but the thing is it only works with the items that are already in the Excel file.

For example, if I try and delete some items than press the button to update again from Jama nothing happens. As a hint my supervisor said I don't need an If condition. I'm new with VBA so your help is very needed.

I have these lines of code:

```
    ' convert to text format
    If rCell.Offset(0, cHeading - 1).NumberFormat = "@" Then
        rCell.Offset(0, cHeading - 1) = oResponseDataLocation("sequence")
    End If

    'Coloring
    If rCell.Offset(0, cHeading - 1) <> sPastCellContant Then
        rCell.Offset(0, cHeading - 1).Interior.ColorIndex = ChangedColour
    End If
```

Comment: we will need a minimal, complete example, and a clear problem description (input, expected output). It is not quite clear what you expect from the code you posted (jama? button? delete items?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block doesn't convert to text format as written in the comment. It only runs the indented line if the cell format is formatted as text already.

```
' convert to text format
If rCell.Offset(0, cHeading - 1).NumberFormat = "@" Then
    rCell.Offset(0, cHeading - 1) = oResponseDataLocation("sequence")
End If
```

I assume your supervisor was right and that this is what you want:

```
' convert to text format
rCell.Offset(0, cHeading - 1).NumberFormat = "@"
rCell.Offset(0, cHeading - 1) = oResponseDataLocation("sequence")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The hint he gave was the solution itself :)